# Can I use "enjoy" in this way?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

"The two countries enjoy economic advantage complementarity, high degree of converging interests and broad prospects for cooperation."

I checked the [Longman dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/ko/dictionary/enjoy) and I guess that "to have a particular ability or advantage" may fit this? But I'm not sure about this, because in the dictionary all subjects are humans, which makes me wonder if it's okay to use it in this way.

Does this sentence make sense in English? Can I use "enjoy" in this way?

Comment: Plenty of people / things [*enjoy economic **parity***,](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22enjoy+economic+parity%22) so I don't see why they can't enjoy ***complementarity***.

Comment: Lexico has a parallel example sentence, with 'the security forces' rather than 'the two countries' as the subject. Both have, of course, _groups_ of **sentient beings** as their referents. I'll look for an example licensing an obviously non-sentient agent.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: There's not really any need to search hard. Estate agents, for example, are always banging on about properties that enjoy impressive freatures.

Comment: [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/enjoy): << **enjoy** ...  [transitive] [formal] {I'd add 'or more often enticing sales-speak for property-, holiday-sellers'} to have something as a benefit or advantage
_The hotel enjoys a magnificent view of the harbor._ >> Estate agents and holiday reps being the new poets, waxing expensively. Expansively.

Comment: "Enjoy" seems to be used correctly, but the sentence is unintelligible.

Comment: Most readers will choke at "complementarity".  Yeah, they will probably be able to parse it, but their train of thought will be lost.  And it will seem like a comma is missing after "advantage".